# Python VK API как получить картинку от пользователя и затем ему же ее отправить?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Начал разбираться в питоне, пробую различные функции vk-api. Сейчас бот принимает любое сообщение и отправляет только определенную картинку. Необходимо чтобы он сразу получил картинку от пользователя и отправил ее ему же. Заранее спасибо.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from activ_token import VK_TOKEN

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=VK_TOKEN)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)


def sender(text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})


def send_photo(url):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'attachment': url, 'random_id': 0})


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id
            sender(msg)
            send_photo('url картинки')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def send_photo(peer_id, attachments, random_id=0):
    vk_session.method('messages.send',
        {"peer_id": peer_id, "attachment": attachments, "random_id": random_id})

for item in event.object['attachments']:
    if item['type'] == 'photo':
        send_photo(event.user_id, 'photo{}_{}'.format(item['owner_id'], item['id']))
```